# LS_COLORS mixing matching criteria, e.g. file extension and hardlink

Tags: ls, colors

I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the characteristic color of the extension type in `ls --color=auto` as well as underlining the file if it is a hard link.

For instance, if I do

```
 LS_COLORS="*.tgz=01;31:mh=04" ls --color=auto foo.tgz
```

I see the file in bold and red, but if I do:

```
ln foo.tgz bar.tgz
LS_COLORS="*.tgz=01;31:mh=04" ls --color=auto foo.tgz
```

now I see the file in white and underline. I would like to see it in bold red and underline, and of course, make this work with other extensions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All* hard-linked files can be shown in bold-red by modifying the command

```
LS_COLORS="*.tgz=01;31:mh=04" ls --color=auto foo.tgz
```

to

```
LS_COLORS="*.tgz=01;31:mh=04;01;31" ls --color=auto foo.tgz
```

The `mh=` part of the `LS_COLORS` variable refers to hard-linked files.  There is a table in the [`ls` source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n555) which does not appear in the documentation:

```
enum indicator_no
  {
    C_LEFT, C_RIGHT, C_END, C_RESET, C_NORM, C_FILE, C_DIR, C_LINK,
    C_FIFO, C_SOCK,
    C_BLK, C_CHR, C_MISSING, C_ORPHAN, C_EXEC, C_DOOR, C_SETUID, C_SETGID,
    C_STICKY, C_OTHER_WRITABLE, C_STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE, C_CAP, C_MULTIHARDLINK,
    C_CLR_TO_EOL
  };

static const char *const indicator_name[]=
  {
    "lc", "rc", "ec", "rs", "no", "fi", "di", "ln", "pi", "so",
    "bd", "cd", "mi", "or", "ex", "do", "su", "sg", "st",
    "ow", "tw", "ca", "mh", "cl", NULL
  };
```

and the `04` is the SGR code (select graphic rendition) for underline.  The `01` and `31` are *bold* and *red*, respectively.  By adding those to the variable in the part for **`mh`**, you can color hard-linked files just like other files (or different, if you choose different numbers).

However, GNU `ls` chooses only one scheme for coloring each file.  The colon `:` separates schemes.  After checking for special categories such as hard-links (and symbolic links and directories), the program *only* looks for suffixes such as `tgz` when none of those categories apply.  In [the source-code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n4429), that is commented

```
  /* Check the file's suffix only if still classified as C_FILE.  */
```

and once it has selected a scheme, it does just that one, [without attempting to combine schemes](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n4453).