# All directories are blue on green on WSL

Tags: bash, ls, windows-subsystem-for-linux

According to all I've read `LS_COLORS` with `di=01;34` should mean bold blue.

No matter what setting I try I cannot get anything except white on black (I assume when my setting is incorrect) or this ugly, standard blue on green.

[image]

I have tried every permutation of `di=**;**:` or, depending on who you ask `dir=**;**:` to no avail and no other result except vanilla or ugly.

What is going on here?

Windows 10 / WSL Ubuntu 20 / Windows Terminal

### LS_COLORS

```bsh
rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33
:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01
:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41
:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42
:st=37;44:ex=01;32: *.tar=01;31
:*.tgz=01;31:*....
```

Comment: Does it work as you expect on a directory that doesn't have `777` permissions? Try `mkdir foo; chmod 755 foo; ls`.

Comment: Related: [What causes this green background in ls output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94498/what-causes-this-green-background-in-ls-output)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LS_COLORS` is not ignored. It's causing the blue on green, which is absolutely not standard. That blue on green is ugly by design: it signals a directory that is world-writable, which is normally rare, but are common on WSL which doesn't use Unix permissions the normal way.

This comes from the `ow` setting in `LS_COLORS`. Replace `ow=34;42` by `ow=` so that the setting doesn't apply.

```
shopt -s extglob
LS_COLORS=${LS_COLORS/:ow=*([^:]):/:ow=:}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `extglob` be disabled after running those commands? by running this command: `shopt -u extglob`

Answer (score 4):

The `ow=34;42` is what's being printed.  If you do a

```
dircolors --print-database
```

you may notice this line:

```
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

which is the **`ow`** code.  That's telling you that you have a world-writable directory.  As I commented in [*LS_COLORS mixing matching criteria, e.g. file extension and hardlink*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225408/ls-colors-mixing-matching-criteria-e-g-file-extension-and-hardlink/293637#293637)

> However, GNU ls chooses only one scheme for coloring each file.

In this case, it sees something more "interesting" in the table than just the file/directory type, and uses that.  Reading the source-code is by the way the only way to understand GNU ls, since its documentation is weak.